# Shell commands in Ipython script

Tags: ipython

Shell commands that work in interactive mode do not work when I run them as a script. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Ingest the data into a giant DataFrame
cd data/raw/
```

If I type the above in the interactive shell, everything is working fine. If I run the script `./myScript.py`, or I just copy the code above and paste it in my interactive shell (starting at the first import), I get:

```
    cd data/raw/
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I feel I'm missing something obvious here but not sure what?

Answer (score 0):

Why is your script a .sh file while you write python code ?

Try with the .ipy extension

Comment: It's actually .py, I changed the question. I did using .ipy extension and that did not make any difference.

Comment: Actually, you were right - I need to precede the call with a % symbol, and use .ipy extension.

Comment: Nice to hear you solved the problem :)